# Overriding ActualWidth and ActualHeight dependency properties

Tags: wpf, overriding, dependency-properties, actualwidth, actualheight

I have a custom line shape with start and end point. The `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties however do not return the correct value, that is the difference between the points. Is there a way to override these properties in the derived class, and how would you go about doing it. I need to use the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties since I am using an algorithm which uses those properties for other shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`, [they are computed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx):

> The value is set by the layout system itself, based on an actual rendering pass

So, what you should do instead is to change how your shape behaves during rendering. Either by the way you override [`DefiningGeometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.defininggeometry.aspx) (assuming your shape is actually `Shape`) or by overriding [`MeasureOverride()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride.aspx).